# How to ensure only single process running in Thread

Tags: python, operating-system, python-asyncio

I have a class method that is of type coroutine , and getting multiple request to it at the same time from one user , suppose user makes a function call at t =0 , and function needs 10 ms for process , user makes another async call at t= 3 ms , then respose to reuest 1 comes at t =10 ms and response to request 2 comes in at t = 20ms ,  so turn around time for request 2  is 17 ms , however i would like following scenario,

If request 1 comes from one user at t = 0 ms , and runs for 3 ms before request 2 comes in at t = 3ms , then  call 1 must be destroyed and call for response 2 must be started , and response to request2 must come back at t=13ms with Turn around time of 10 ms.

Something like ensuring single process run for each user .
So if there is a function

```
  def Myfunction(a,b):
     return a+b

  #user calls
  #at t = 0
  myfunction(10,5) #takes 10 ms

  #at t=3 
  myfunction(100,200)#takes 10 ms

  so  i want that myfunction must have only single/latest call  instance running  for each user i.e in above case only myfunction(100,200) my be occupying the the CPU after t=3 .
```

I am using python asyncio library and yield from statements and event loops.

Kindly provide some idea how to implement above idea.

Comment: Just to be sure, waiting for user response to start a thread, then you want to destroy that thread if user invokes the same thing again and start it all over again ?

Comment: yes i want to destroy that thread if user invokes the same thing again to empty CPU for new call

Comment: Are you aware your code does not create a new thread ?

Comment: In asyncio , the process runs in a single event loop which runs in a single thread , however i tried creating new event loop and calling this function in it  explicitly whenever function was invoked , however in this scenario also i got delay in simultaneous function call response.

Answer (score 0):

In asyncio, you would be using tasks to handle this. You keep track of the currently running function, and cancel it when it is called again

```
_running = None
async def wrapped_myfunction():
    global _running
    if _running is not None:
        _running.cancel()
    _running = asyncio.create_task(myfunction())
    return await _running
```